# Elegant way to apply UDF by condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have some input files, and all the files share the same schema. They both have a field named `channel_id`, but for `file1`, `channel_id = 1`, for `file2`, `channel_id = 2`.

I need to do some ETL on these files. However, for different files, the logic is different. For example, there is a UDF to calculate `channel_name`

```
val getChannelNameUdf : UserDefinedFunction = udf((channelId: Integer) => {
    if (channelId == 1) {
      "English"
    } else if (channelId == 2) {
      "French"
    } else {
      ""
    }
  })
```

As we have several channels, it seems not elegant to use `if-else`. Are there more elegant ways or suitable design patterns to write the code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Brooklyn and welcome to StackOverflow,

You can use a Pattern matching in your UDF but I'd suggest you to use the `when` built-in function instead of defining your own UDF.

To answer your request, here's the code you may need :

```
val getChannelNameUdf = udf[String, Int] { _ match {
  case 1 => "English"
  case 2 => "French"
  case _ => ""
}}
```

or even better, just anonymous functions :

```
val getChannelNameUdf = udf[String, Int] {
  case 1 => "English"
  case 2 => "French"
  case _ => ""
}
```

Here's an example using the when built-in function :

```
val getChannelName = {col: Column =>
  when(col === 1, "English").when(col === 2, "French").otherwise("")
}
df.withColumn("channelName", getChannelName($"channelId"))
```

**Edit :** For a more generic approach you can use the following definitions :

```
val rules = Map(1 -> "English", 2 -> "French")
val getChannelName = {col: Column =>
  rules.foldLeft(lit("")){case (c, (i,label)) =>
    when(col === i, label).otherwise(c)
  }
}
```

and then

```
df.withColumn("channelName", getChannelName($"channelId"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are there more elegant ways or suitable design patterns to write the code?

Yes! A simple and efficient way of doing this would be to use `join`.

You can have a file with all the referential of channels, say it has this structure: `channel_id, channel_name`, and then join the 2 DataFrames. Something like this:

```
val df_channels = spark.read.csv("/path/to/channel_file.csv")

val result = df.join(df_channels, Seq("channel_id"),"left")
```